# How is it possible that a handMade dictionary is way faster than .Net dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections

Reviewing one opensource project, I've come across one interesting Data structure:

```
// Represents a layer of "something" that covers the map
public class CellLayer<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public readonly Size Size;
    public readonly TileShape Shape;
    public event Action<CPos> CellEntryChanged = null;

    readonly T[] entries;

    public CellLayer(Map map)
        : this(map.TileShape, new Size(map.MapSize.X, map.MapSize.Y)) { }

    public CellLayer(TileShape shape, Size size)
    {
        Size = size;
        Shape = shape;
        entries = new T[size.Width * size.Height];
    }

    public void CopyValuesFrom(CellLayer<T> anotherLayer)
    {
        if (Size != anotherLayer.Size || Shape != anotherLayer.Shape)
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "layers must have a matching size and shape.", "anotherLayer");
        if (CellEntryChanged != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Cannot copy values when there are listeners attached to the CellEntryChanged event.");
        Array.Copy(anotherLayer.entries, entries, entries.Length);
    }

    // Resolve an array index from cell coordinates
    int Index(CPos cell)
    {
        return Index(cell.ToMPos(Shape));
    }

    // Resolve an array index from map coordinates
    int Index(MPos uv)
    {
        return uv.V * Size.Width + uv.U;
    }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the <see cref="OpenRA.CellLayer"/> using cell coordinates</summary>
    public T this[CPos cell]
    {
        get
        {
            return entries[Index(cell)];
        }

        set
        {
            entries[Index(cell)] = value;

            if (CellEntryChanged != null)
                CellEntryChanged(cell);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the layer contents using raw map coordinates (not CPos!)</summary>
    public T this[MPos uv]
    {
        get
        {
            return entries[Index(uv)];
        }

        set
        {
            entries[Index(uv)] = value;

            if (CellEntryChanged != null)
                CellEntryChanged(uv.ToCPos(Shape));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Clears the layer contents with a known value</summary>
    public void Clear(T clearValue)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < entries.Length; i++)
            entries[i] = clearValue;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator<T>)entries.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

This structure represents a matrix of type T in that, given a CPos (an X,Y) structure, it returns the T element at that position. Here's one sample usage:

```
var dic = new CellLayer<CellInfo>(TileShape.Rectangle, new Size(1280,1280));
cellLayer[new CPos(0, 1)] = new CellInfo(0, new CPos(0, 1), false);
```

Internally, the CellLayer class transforms the given CPos into a int which operates as the index for the internal array.

By the looks of how the class operates from a client-side perspective, it felt to me like a Dictionary, so I replaced the implementation. After several runtimes tests and microbenchmarking, it turned out that using the dictionary was dozens of times slower than using the handmade CellLayer class. That surprised me. Here are the tests I did:

```
    [Test]
    public void DictionaryTest()
    {
        var dic = new Dictionary<CPos, CellInfo>(1280 * 1280);

        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1280; i++)
            for (int u = 0; u < 1280; u++)
                dic[new CPos(i, u)] = new CellInfo(0, new CPos(i, u), false);

        Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedTicks);
    }

    [Test]
    public void CellLayerTest()
    {
        var dic = new CellLayer<CellInfo>(TileShape.Rectangle, new Size(1280,1280));

        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1280; i++)
            for (int u = 0; u < 1280; u++)
                dic[new CPos(i, u)] = new CellInfo(0, new CPos(i, u), false);

        Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedTicks);
    }
```

I thought that .NET Collections were as optimized as possible. Can anyone explain to me how is it that using Dictionary is slower that using a "custom Dictionary"?

Thanks

Comment: `CellLayer` is IEnumerable not a dictionary. Compare it with List or an array

Comment: Does your `CPos` object implement `IEquatable<CPos>`?

Comment: Assuming `CPos` is a X-Y coordinate tuple and that the X-Y pairs are unique as in your tests, please rethink: what is faster, a hash-keyed Dicitonary with hashes and collisions, or a 2D array with proper size and full random access along both dimensions?

Comment: @EZI sorry, it was I who introduced the IEnumerable interface while doing some test to that class. That interface is irrelevant, I just put it to make it foreach compatible.

Yuval No it doesn't

Comment: How does `CPos` access its indexer? via X-Y coordinate? that should be O(1), where a dictionary should also be roughly around O(1) given good dispersion.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I Guess you are right on that point.

Yuval Itzchakov yeah it transforms the X-Y coordinate into a single int. Both should be O(1) but the O(1) of the dictionary is far slower though.

Comment: I'd like to add a note: the fact that CellLayer provides you with a `[ ]`-operator that doesn't take a `int` as indexing parameter, does not make the `CellLayer` a "dictionary". I guess that it is just a smart array that is indexed by "points" that are simply multiplied and mapped right into physical array coords.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Definitely. This isn't a dictionary, simply an array indexer access for a 2D array.

Comment: @DavidJiménezMartínez Does `CPos` implement `IEquatable<CPos>`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov nope it doesn't

Comment: @DavidJiménezMartínez Try implementing `IEquatable<CPos>` with a good override of `GetHashCode` and `Equals` test your code again

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I've made CPos Equatable with the following hash function: public override int GetHashCode() { return X.GetHashCode() ^ Y.GetHashCode(); }. Still CellLayer beats Dictionary by a myriad.

Comment: Could you please post either the full source of the CellLayer or a link to the source?  I have a feeling it has to do with collisions, but can't test that theory without the source.

Comment: @Qwerty01 find the CellLayer source here: https://github.com/OpenRA/OpenRA/blob/bleed/OpenRA.Game/Map/CellLayer.cs

Comment: @DavidJiménezMartínez: all relevant code should be included in the question itself. Please do not use external links to provide important details, and please _do_ fix your question so that it includes [a _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing everything relevant to the question.

Comment: If you can implement the IDictionary interface, then it is a dictionary. Not all dictionaries are hash tables and not all hash tables are dictionaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the original version, you find the location of an entry by using this formula

```
uv.V * Size.Width + uv.U
```

To find the location in a dictionary

1. Calculate the hash code for CPos.
2. Find the bucket in the dictionary using a modulus operation `hashcode % dictionarySize`
3. If the bucket isn't empty, compare the CPos you have with the CPos in that bucket. If they don't match you have a secondary hash code collision. Move to the next bucket and retry step 3.

If you have a primary has code collision, which is to say lots of different CPos values have the same hash code, your dictionary is going to be ridiculously slow.

If you have unique hash codes, then it is probably the modulus operation that is killing performance. But you would need to attach a profiler (e.g. Redgate ANTS) to find out for sure.

Answer (score -1):

A dictionary maintains an *search/retrievable* set of itmes (either through a hash-table, a binary tree or something similar). So each `Add()` and each `[key]` implies some *search* (which tends to be relatively "slow").

In your case, if there is a simple mapping from a `CPos` to an integer (aka array index) there is no search but a direct (and fast) access to a cell of an array.

Or, to put it simpler: Essentially you compare a hash table/binary tree against a flat array.

---

**Edit**

Of course both collections are rather fast and show O(1) compexity. A lookup in a hash table is more complex than an array index operation however.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting your information, but `Dictionary` is not ordered, it uses a hash table to allow O(1) access, there is no "searching" done in a dictionary to add (unless there is collisions, giving an O(n) worst case)

Comment: @DrKoch This information is *wrong*. A dictionary isn't an *ordered set of items*. Each `Add` call is inserted into a bucket by retrieving the objects hash code along with more calculations. You should look into how the implementation of [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0) to understand how it works.